# audio jack does not detect external input

Tags: audio

I tried to connect my vinyl record player to my laptop as an external input using an RCA to 3.5mm cable. However, my laptop detects it as a headphone instead of an input device. Is there any way I can force to detect it as an input device? The cable does work properly when I connect it to a external speaker (for playing the record).

Comment: Did you connect it to the microphone jack?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give up on that & buy a dedicated [RIAA preamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization) with a USB connection. You cannot plug a record deck straight into any amplifier, analog, digital or computer.

You **must** go through an RIAA pre-amp first, or it will sound abysmal; thin, nasty & very weak signal.

If you have one on your hi-fi already, then figure a way to feed that to the computer - use the cassette output or similar.

Comment: Thank you. I'm kind of new to stuff like this, but I could directly connect my turntable to a speaker and play with decent sound quality. So, would there be a way to somehow direct that signal to my computer instead?

Comment: You cannot in any way, shape or form plug a record deck straight into a speaker.. you must have an RIAA preamplifier & then an amplifier between the two. If it sounds vaguely OK, then something is performing those functions, even if you are mis-identifying them.